# How does "reveal a card, play it, then return it" work with locations?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building, dc-comics-deck-building-rivals

During a game of *DC Comics Deckbuilding Game: Rivals*, we had a strange situation (which could also happen in the base game).

The Joker's second form says the following:

> Once during each of your turns, if you play a Villain and a Super Power, reveal the top card of the main deck. Play it, then return it.

The player activated this ability and drew a location, which says the following:

> When you play this card, leave it in front of you for the rest of the game.

Which instruction wins? We have one effect that says we have to return the card and another that says we have to leave it in front of you for the rest of the game.

Answer (score -1):

The joker's ability card would take priority. You would play the location card. Take any effect the location card gives you then return it at the end of your turn. For example Wayne Manor

> When you play your first HERO on each of your turns draw a card.

So on your turn if you play a villain, you draw wayne manor and then you play a hero you get a card draw and then you put wayne manor back at the top of the deck when you're done with your turn.

Comment: What is the basis for the Joker's ability taking priority? Also, wouldn't Wayne Manor not take effect, because you didn't play a Hero Card in the brief time it was out (you were in the middle of playing a Villain or Super Power card, which triggered the Joker's ability)?